# How to prove that two lines are not parallel?

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

Given the points in the three-dimensional affine space $A = (1, 1, 1)$, $B = (-2, -1, 0)$.

• Find the Cartesian equations of line $r$ for points $A$, $B$.

I found it and it is:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x-3z+2=0 \\ 
y-2z+1=0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Correct me if it's wrong. Now given the line $r'$ of parametric equations:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x=1+3t' \\ 
y=-2 \\ 
z=1-t'
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

with $t'∈R$, how can I prove that the lines $r$ and $r'$ are not parallel?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: a direction vector of the first line is given by  $A-B=(3,2,1)$, while a direction vector of the second line (look at the coefficients of $t'$) is $(3,0,-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the **direction vector $\vec v$**, you need to consider the **parametric equations** $P_0+\vec vt$ for the two lines

- parametric equation for line $r$ is: $$A+(A-B)t=(1,1,1)+t(3,2,1)$$
- parametric equation for line $r'$ is: $$(1,-2,1)+t'(3,0,-1)$$

Since $v_r=(3,2,1) \not \parallel v_r'=(3,0,-1)$ the two lines are not parallel.

Comment: This works, but you don't _need_ to set up a parametric equation of $r$ to say something about being parellel or not to $r'$, it suffices to compute a direction vector.

Comment: @StackTD yes of course and your answer contains all the necessary information, but I think that derive the full parametric equation can be also useful to Mark to better understand the meaning of each term

Comment: Of course it's useful to understand how parametric equations work, but I think it's a bit misleading to claim that you _need_ the parametric equation. This tends to cause students to follow standard procedures for certain problems and often doing _too much_, without really thinking about what they (really) need and how to achieve that in an efficient way. It's just a comment :).

Comment: @StackTD ah ok now I git your point, I clarify better that!

Comment: I wrote that since $v_r × v_r'$ is not equal to $(0,0,0)$ then the two lines are not parallel. Is it right?

Comment: @MarkB That's  fine, but a bit overkill. If you have $v_r$ and $v_r'$, it suffices to see if they are scalar multiples of one another (and avoid having to compute the cross product).

Comment: @MarkB Yes it is correct but unnecessary in this case, you can simply scale one vector in such way that one component of  one vectors is equal to the corresponding component of the second, if they are not equal than the vector are not parallel (in your case x=3 for both vectors but y and z are different).

Comment: I also found that the two lines are incident because $v_r×u_r'≠0$ and the two lines are skew because the determinant of the matrix is $≠0$